# How is the Firewall taking priority over other applications when the PC first boots?

Tags: windows, networking, security, firewall, services

How is the Firewall taking priority over other applications when the PC first boots? How is the priority given,is it through a kernel driver?

I'm using Comodo Firewall and I see that the Spotify app is loading before Comodo loads;well it seems like that since the Spotify panel appears before the Comodo one.I mean the Firewall has to start first before other applications can access the internet,isn't that so?

That might be ok for Spotify but what if there is a rogue app that gets access to the internet before the firewall does? How can you prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How is the Firewall taking priority over other applications when the PC first boots?

> I'm using Comodo Firewall and I see that the Spotify app is loading before Comodo loads; well it seems like that since the Spotify panel appears before the Comodo one.

The apps that you see loading are the GUI components of Spotify and Comodo.

These GUI components are loaded during logon. At this point the protection parts of Comodo are already loaded so the system is secure.

- The protection parts of Comodo (`cmdagent.exe` and the Inspect packet filter driver `inspect.sys`) are loaded very early in the boot process (before explorer starts).
- Inspect runs at the lowest level (kernel level).

> The processes that protect are actually Comodo Internet Security Helper Service (cmdagent.exe) and the Inspect packet filter driver (which runs under Comodo Internet Security Helper Service).
>
> They start very early in the boot process. Cis.exe is the client program; it is the program that provides the UI and instructs cmdagent.exe how to behave. Cistray.exe provides the tray icon, widget and starts cis.exe.
>
> Protection is provided regardless whether cistray.exe and cis.exe are running.

Source [Why does cis.exe get launched as a service?](https://forums.comodo.com/install-setup-configuration-help-cis/why-does-cisexe-get-launched-as-a-service-t113284.0.html;msg821544#msg821544)

> CIS uses WFP in conjunction with inspect.sys packet filter driver. Inspect runs at the lowest level (kernel level) where WFP runs at higher levels.

Source [Is CIS using Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) or what?](https://forums.comodo.com/firewall-help-cis/is-cis-using-windows-filtering-platform-wfp-or-what-t103704.0.html;msg757415#msg757415)

---

#### What if there is a rogue app that gets access to the internet before the firewall does? How can you prevent that?

A Firewall will not prevent the installation of rogue apps. You need another layer of security to do this, for example an AntiVirus program.

There are also progams that will monitor system changes. I use
[WinPatrol](https://www.winpatrol.com/winpatrol/) which has the following alerts:

> - New Start-up Programs
>
>   Spyware and Malware need to start in order to run. Protect your
>     startup programs.
> - New Browser Add-ons
>
>   Don’t let unwanted add-ons invade your privacy, commandeer or slow
>     down your Internet browsing.
> - New Browser Toolbars
>
>   Unwanted toolbars slow your browser down and have the potential
>     invade your privacy.
> - Newly installed Windows Services
>
>   A Windows Service has total permission to EVERYTHING on your
>     computer. You NEED to know when one is installed and why!
> - Creation of Scheduled Tasks
>
>   Scheduled tasks are a way spyware and malware will schedule one of
>     their minions to run. Don’t let them use your task scheduler against
>     you.
> - Changes in File Type Associations
>
>   Malware will typically change file type associations to get you to
>     run their program. In addition, this helps to prevent file hi-jacking
>     of file type associations by impolite programs.
> - Newly Active-X components
>
>   You need to know what is installed on your computer.
> - Changes to your home page
>
>   Don’t let programs get away with changing your homepage without your
>     permission.
> - Changes to your default Internet search provider
>
>   Junkware, malware and unscrupulous entities love to change your
>     search provider so they can control the results.
> - Changes to your hosts file
>
>   This protects you for malware redirecting to you their site rather
>     than the real site.
> - Changes to Auto Updates Settings
>
>   Malware loves to disable auto updates, stop them in their tracks!
> - Changes to UAC Settings
>
>   Don’t let programs change your UAC Settings without your knowledge.
> - Changes to Hidden Files
>
>   Get alerted if any new hidden files are added or changed.

Source [WinPatrol](https://www.winpatrol.com/winpatrol/)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [WinPatrol](https://www.winpatrol.com/winpatrol/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. Is Defense+ of the Comodo Internet Security alike WinPatrol? and, can virus programs use the same technique employed by Comodo for loading early or first?

Comment: There appears to be some overlap between WinPatrol and Defense+, but Defense+ seems more like an AntiVirus. Virus programs can do anything they are programmed/allowed to do. They could load early (as a service) if not caught before installation by AntiVirus or other software. That's one of the reasons I run WinPatrol (it alerts for "Newly installed Windows Services"). **"A Windows Service has total permission to EVERYTHING on your computer. You NEED to know when one is installed and why!"**